# Как вывести вес продукта в Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Нашел файл отвечающий за вывод цены, под её строкой или в ней со знаком дробь хочу вставить код выводящий вес продукта в граммах. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой должен быть код. Путь к файлу: : app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml

```html
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
     <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $weeeAmountToDisplay, true, true) ?>
</span>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: $product->getWeight()
Но самого объекта продукта в вашем примере не вижу.

Comment: К сожалению, в этом не разбираюсь... По логике нашёл строку, что выводит цену продукта и по идее под ней должен написать что-то аналогичное, только выводящее вес. Возможно в хмл файле нужно будет добавить блок. Но а в принципе это блок цены, туда и добавить граммовку. А в примере код выводящий цену для каждого продукта.

Comment: Неправильно в шаблон с ценой засовывать что-то еще.

Comment: Дело в том, что к примеру в ресторанах цена идёт сразу с граммовкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                     <?php echo  $pro->getWeight(); ?><?php echo $this->__('гр');?>
                </span>
```

Comment: 1. Посмотрите как увеличится количество запросов к базе данных.  Этот код выполняется в цикле и приведет к увеличению времени загрузки страницы. 2. $this->__('гр'); - это метод который отвечает за переводы. Для того чтобы перевести надо использовать файлы переводов csv.